# Why retainCount = 2 - after release?

Tags: ios, memory-management, retaincount

I use this code.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    view = [[UIView alloc] init];

    [_window addSubview:view];

    [view release];

    NSLog(@"count - %d", [view retainCount]);

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;

}


- (IBAction)click{

    NSLog(@"count - %d", [view retainCount]); 

}
```

When i click to uibutton - my view retain count = 2. 
Why is this happening?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is the retain count so high? Memory Management](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712478/why-is-the-retain-count-so-high-memory-management)

Comment: Have you ever tried to first `removeFromSuperView` then call `release` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please **do not** count on retainCount. Fire up Instruments and see if there is a leak. Apple discourages the use of retainCount for debugging purposes:

> **Important**: This method is typically of
>   no value in debugging memory
>   management issues. Because any number
>   of framework objects may have retained
>   an object in order to hold references
>   to it, while at the same time
>   autorelease pools may be holding any
>   number of deferred releases on an
>   object, it is very unlikely that you
>   can get useful information from this
>   method.

Have a look at the [NSObjectProtocol and the retainCount](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/retainCount) documentation. Read the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1) for a deeper understanding of retain counts.

Comment: +1. I was searching for the reference from developer site. Thanks you gave it.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, it could be retained by `_window` or other objects, so if you call `[view retainCount];` in `dealloc` method you'll probably get `retain count = 0`.

As Nick Weaver said, don't use `retainCount` in any way then detecting leaks while debugging memory issues.

Answer (score 0):

It is better we  not mind value of retainCount. 
Simply follow the memory management rules - take ownership when you need them, relinquish ownership when you are finished, and you will not have a problem.

If you are looking at retainCount, you are going about things the wrong way, and you will simply confuse yourself .

The only rule  about the amount of times you can retain an object is that each retain must be balanced with a release.