# Memory management of UITableViewController, UITableView & UIPopoverController

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, uipopovercontroller

I trying to figure out the best way to perform memory management on the following implementation:

I've a UIPopoverController which will be created upon viewDidLoad of the view and only be gone when viewDidUnload.

And Inside the UIPopoverController, I'm displaying a UITableView.

Here is my current implementation in .h:

```
UIPopoverController *aPopoverController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPopoverController *aPopoverController;
```

In .m:

```
@synthesize *aPopoverController;
```

Inside a method in .m which is called when viewDidLoad:

```
UITableViewController *aTableViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

UITableView *aTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 800)];
aTableViewController.tableView = aTableView;

aTableView.delegate = self;
aTableView.dataSource = self;

aPopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:aTableViewController];
```

How should I release these objects when viewDidUnload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feel free to release both `aTableView` and `aTableViewController` right after this code.

To be more specific, `UITableViewController` retains the table view, so you don't need to keep it anymore, and `UIPopoverController` retains the content view controller, so you can release `aTableViewController` once you passed it to the popover controller.

In `-viewDidUnload` your popover controller is released, and it releases table view controller, which then releases the table view. Simple as that.

I'd put it like this:

```
UITableViewController *aTableViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

UITableView *aTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 800)];
aTableView.delegate = self;
aTableView.dataSource = self;
aTableViewController.tableView = aTableView;
[aTableView release];

aPopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:aTableViewController];
[aTableViewController release];
```

Comment: hi @ayoy, thanks! I released `aTableView` and `aTableViewController`. I checked the retain counts of 3 objects, both `aTableViewController` and `aPopoverController` returns me 1. Any idea why is the `aTableView`'s retain count is still at 2. I assumed it should be 1 since `aTableView` is only retained by `aTableViewController`. If not, when I try to release `aTableView` at viewDidUnload, it's count still still be at 1.

Comment: I realized `aTableViewController.tableView = aTableView` also increases the `atableView`'s retain count. Do have to do a `aTableViewController.tableView = nil` at viewdidUnload?

Comment: Yes, it increases `aTableView` retain count so that it could use it later. It should be your only retain source, and that's why you could (and should) release `aTableView` right after that call and just forget about it. I'm wondering where the second retain comes from...

Comment: I always thought `UITableView *aTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 800)];` will set the retain count to 1. Then `aTableViewController.tableView = aTableView` would increase the retain count to 2?

Comment: Yes, but after a call to `release` it should get back to 1. And you've said in the first comment that you released it and it's still at 2.

Comment: I'm using `retainCount` and I just found out that it should [not be used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276442/why-retaincount-2-after-release) since it may not be accurate. That explains why the retain count is the same before and after did a `[aTableView release]`.

Comment: Off the main question, is there any other way to check if I'm doing proper memory management or the only way to go is to use leak instruments?

Comment: None that I know of. I rely only on Instruments, it's an outstanding tool after all :)

Comment: Alright, thanks so much for your answers and comments. Have a great day/night whereever you are from!