# Can an Objective-C object's retain count drop below zero?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, release, dealloc, retaincount

I have learned manual memory management in Objective-C and every article said: "When the retain count of an object drops to 0, the dealloc method is called and the object is destroyed". And nothing more.

But there is no answer for several questions: Can I drop the retain count below 0? Is it possible to call `[object release]` several times in a row, before the object dies, and cause the retain count to drop below 0? And if I've done so, will the Universe still exist?

Google gives me nothing, like: "Why would you even ask this question? Nobody cares. Go and read about memory management once more."

Comment: Try searching for "over releasing objective c"

Comment: Actually, what I should have said is: What happened when you tried it? Your question is easily answered by experiment.

Comment: No, universe will not exist any more. You will get crash BAD_ACCESS somewhere. Haven't you tried it by yourself? Quite admirable, that you are learning about manual memory management, it will help you understand thing from inside. But it is quite unsafely and in modern projects doesn't used.

Comment: You might be interested in [Objects' retain counts never go below 1 despite deliberately overreleasing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4927613)

Comment: The current runtime (going back several releases, at least) never drops the count to zero.  Instead, when it would have decremented to zero, it just skips that part and calls `dealloc`.  See the numerous questions asking why `retainCount` reports 1 for a `dealloc`ed object.

Answer (score 2):

If you call `release` when the retain count is `1`, `dealloc` is immediately called. So the retain count doesn't ever even get to `0`.

Further calls to `release` will cause a runtime crash as you would be dereferencing a deallocated object.

So no, the universe won't exist at that point :)

Comment: Note that the retain count never drops to zero;  the runtime doesn't waste the cycles decrementing prior to destroying the object.

Comment: Thanks for the extra details @bbum, I updated the answer!

Answer (score -3):

A retain count can be 0 or higher but never less. When an object is allocated heap memory (`alloc init`) the retain count is set to 1. You can then increase the retain count by calling `retain` on it (as far as I'm aware an unlimited number of times but I could be wrong).

Calling `release` simply decreased the retain count by 1. The system then periodically checks the retain counts of objects and deallocates any with a count of 0.

Calling `release` on an already deallocated object is the same as calling any method on a `NULL` object and should simply return `NULL` or `void`. However, if you are explicilty managing heap memory then you should be **VERY** aware of what you're doing.

Some interesting points:

> Why can a retain count be more that 1?

This is so that an object isn't released whilst it is still required by something else. E.g. say you have `pet` `owner` and `vet`. A `pet` instance is owned by an `owner` instance. The `owner` goes to a `vet` instance and the `vet` takes ownership of the `pet` also. For a period of time `pet` has two owners and therefore (if `retain` has been called) has a retain count of 2. Lets say that the `owner` is then released before the `vet` has finished with the `pet`; if everything has been done properly the `pet` wont be deallocated it will simply have its reatain count decreased to 1 by the call to `release` from `owner`. The `vet` can then finish with the `pet`, call `release` and the `pet` will be deallocated.

> ARC

As I'm sure you're aware this has all been replaced by **Automatic Reference Counting**. As developers we now have to simple be aware of the type of relationship an object has with another.

Therefore if you create an object now it will be deallocated when it fall out of scope ***unless*** it has a strong relationship (is owned) by another object. You can still get reatain cycles where two objects have strong relationships to each other and therefore never qualify for deallocation.

Appologies for the very long winded answer but memory management is a core part of application programming and is very interesting.

Comment: "Calling release on an already deallocated object is the same as calling any method on a NULL" Only if the pointer was actually set to `nil`. Sending `release` to a deallocated object is programmer error: undefined behavior.

Comment: This answer starts very wrong.  The retain count can **never be 0**. The system **does not** periodically check anything.  Calling a method on a deallocated object is undefined behavior and will oft crash, it is **not at all** like calling any method on `NULL`.    The `vet`/`owner`/`pet` analogy is spot on though.