# Objective-C Retain Count goes from 0 to 2

Tags: objective-c, singleton, retaincount

I'm new to Objective-C. This is my first post here. I created a singleton for the purpose of managing my applications interface to a database. To start out simple, I have used an NSMutableArray as an ivar. As you will see in the code below and the log output, the retain count is 0 before it is assigned to an NSMutableArray object, and then the retain count is 2 after the assignment.

I am not clear why this happens. Is it because the [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:(id)] creates an object with a retain count of one and then the assignment self.dataList increments the retain count? Is it safe to call release once? That doesn't seem like the right thing to do.

Here is the source

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface DataInterfaceObject : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray *dataList;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *dataList;

+ (id) sharedAlloc;

@end
```

...

```
#import "DataInterface.h"

static DataInterfaceObject *sharedDataInterfaceObject = nil;

@implementation DataInterfaceObject

@synthesize dataList;

+ (id) sharedAlloc {    
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (sharedDataInterfaceObject == nil) 
            sharedDataInterfaceObject = [super alloc];
    }
    return sharedDataInterfaceObject;
}

+ (id) alloc {
    return [[self sharedAlloc] init];
}

- (id)init 
{
    @synchronized(self) {
        NSLog(@"In DataInterface init 1, RetainCount for dataList is %d", [self.dataList retainCount]);
        if (dataList == nil) {
            self = [super init];
            if (self) {
                //Instantiate list
                NSLog(@"In DataInterface init 2, RetainCount for dataList is %d", [self.dataList retainCount]);
                self.dataList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Dog", @"Cat", @"Homer", @"Vanessa", @"Tour Eiffel", @"Ball", @"Lettuce", nil];
                NSLog(@"In DataInterface init 3, RetainCount for dataList is %d", [self.dataList retainCount]);
            }
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc 
{
    [dataList release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

The log shows the following:

```
2011-04-06 21:18:26.931 jobs[11672:207] initislized
2011-04-06 21:18:26.933 jobs[11672:207] In DataInterface init 1, RetainCount for dataList is 0
2011-04-06 21:18:26.934 jobs[11672:207] In DataInterface init 2, RetainCount for dataList is 0
2011-04-06 21:18:26.934 jobs[11672:207] In DataInterface init 3, RetainCount for dataList is 2
```

Comment: Have you tried a release statement to see what happens?

Comment: Hey, it’s another question for @bbum. He’s probably got a canned answer by now.

Comment: Happily, the community of relatively new folks have it covered!  No need for me to shout anymore. :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730804/how-many-times-do-i-release-an-allocated-or-retained-object/3730835#3730835 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636146/when-to-use-retaincount

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code:

```
[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Dog", @"Cat", @"Homer", @"Vanessa",
    @"Tour Eiffel", @"Ball", @"Lettuce", nil];
```

Creates an autoreleased variable with a retain count of 1 that will be released sometime in the future. Your property also calls retain so the object will have a retain count of 2 when the print statement is called and then will soon be reduced to 1.

Comment: Where ‘soon’ means whenever the corresponding autorelease pool is drained, usually (but not necessarily) when the run loop iterates.

Comment: Best to think of retain counts purely as deltas, not as absolute nums.  Btw;  in the above, all those string objects have an absolute[ly useless] retain count of ~2147483647

Answer (score 4):

Don't use retain counts for debugging, you'll go crazy. If you're having trouble with memory leaks or over-releasing, make sure you're following the memory management rules.

[Cocoa Core Competencies](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html)

Cocoa With Love has a good article about [creating singletons in Cocoa](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the reason it goes straight to two is that a) you create the object and b) you retain the object by assigning it to self.dataList. You're not responsible for the creation of the object, though, since you didn't call +alloc, so it's fine for your -dealloc to release dataList only once.

That said, @Terry Wilcox is right: don't look at -retainCount.