# Objective C Issue With Rounding Float

Tags: iphone, objective-c, floating-point, double, decimal

I have an issue with rounding the result of a calculation to two decimal places.

It is a financial calculation and when the result involves half a penny I would expect the number to be rounded up but it is in fact being rounded down.

To replicate the issue:

```
float raw = 16.695;
NSLog(@"All DP: %f",raw);
NSLog(@"2 DP: %.2f",raw);
```

Returns:

```
All DP: 16.695000
2 DP: 16.69
```

Whereas I would expect to see:

```
All DP: 16.695000
2 DP: 16.70
```

Can anyone advise if this is by design or if (most likely) I am missing something and if there is anything I can do to get around it.  It is vital that it rounds up in this scenario.

Thanks in advance,
Oli

Comment: Try NSLog(@"9 DP: %.9f",raw); and you will get: 16.694999695

Comment: if you use double precision it will round up in your example

Comment: OK, so that works but out of interest, why? Why doesn't it store the number as 16.695 as was set?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [Don't use `float`s for financial calculations!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61872/use-float-or-decimal-for-accounting-application-dollar-amount)

There are values that floats [*cannot* represent exactly](http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/rounding/). `16.695` is one of them. When you try to store that value in a float, you actually get the closest representable value. When you perform a series of operations on a float, you [can lose precision](http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/propagation/), and then you lose accuracy. This leads to losing money.

Use an actual currency type, use [NSDecimalNumber](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/), or do all your calculations with `int`s that count the smallest unit you care about (i.e., `1050` is $10.50 in whole cents, or $1.050 if you want fractions of pennies).

Comment: I believe this style of post is know as the ["bbum"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730804/how-many-times-do-i-release-an-allocated-or-retained-object/3730835#3730835), and I've heard they're considering adding it to SO as a formatting tag: `<bbum></bbum>`.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I am aware the `NSLog()` function only takes formatting arguments and makes no attempt to round.

You may be use to using a `printf()` style function that does support rounding.

I suggest using one of the many functions in `math.h` to round your value before output and only rely on `NSLog()` for formatting.

Comment: Thanks but the NSLog is just for this example - in the real application I am using [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f,xxx].  I was led to believe this did rounding in the same way printf() did.  What function are you suggesting?

Answer (score 0):

After seeing the comments

Use the C standard function family **round(). roundf()** for **float, round()** for **double,** and **roundl()** for **long double**. You can then cast the result to the integer type of your choice

Answer (score -1):

you could try this:

```
 - (void)testNSlogMethod {

    float value = 16.695; //--16.70
    value = value *100;

    int mulitpler = round(value);

    NSLog(@"%.2f",mulitpler/100.0f);
}
```