# How do I get the floatValue Amount of a Currency-Formatted Label?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a Label, let's call it currencyFormattedLabel, the value of which was earlier formatted in another method as currency (with currencyFormatter).

Now, I want to use the number equivalent in that Label.  However, when i go to get the number, I only get a value of 0.00.

Maybe this will help explain:

```
float x = [currencyFormattedLabel.text floatValue];
NSLog(@"x = %.2f", x);
```

So, if the currencyFormattedLabel is $2.00, this method always ends up returning:  x = 0.00
What i want is for it to return x = 2.00.

Is there a way to take my currencyFormattedLabel and get the number value of it?

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: What value is returned by currencyFormattedLabel.text? Is it what you expect?

Comment: hint: NSLog(@"text = %@", currencyFormattedLabel.text);

Comment: Also, [don't use floats for money](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333711/objective-c-issue-with-rounding-float/6334471#6334471). You should really be getting an integer value that reprents cents instead.

Comment: @Josh, but then I can't siphon off a fraction of a cent from every transaction and transfer it to my offshore account. ha. (+1 for you)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use:

```
float x = [[currencyFormattedTextLabel.text substringFromIndex:1] floatValue];
```

if you knew the number would always be predceeded by a dollar sign.

Answer (score 1):

The dollar sign in the NSString is throwing things off. You will have better luck using NSScanner.

```
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:currencyFormattedLabel.text];
float x;
[scanner scanFloat: &x];
NSLog(@"x = %.2f", x);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this suggestion!!  NSScanner is something I've never used before and when I add it to my code, the answer I get no matter what is in my originally currencyFormattedLabel is -2.00.  What does the & do in the  [scanner scanFLoat: &x]; command do? I suspect that may be the source of it still not working.

Comment: The & is just the syntax used for passing in a reference (or address/pointer) to a variable. I doubt that's causing the issue. I would log the NSString to be absolutely sure you have what you think you have. NSLog(@"text = %@", currencyFormattedLabel.text);